# Logback doesn't show stacktrace

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-boot, logback

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.0 and I don't see exception stack trace in the console.

Everything else is logged, the SQL, transaction start and rollback (when exception occurs) but I don't see them. Does anyone have some ideas?

logback.xml in resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
<jmxConfigurator/>

<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

<logger name="org.apt.crm" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.transaction" level="DEBUG"/>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
// Core
// ====
// Spring Boot
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
if (!buildWar)
{
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
}
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
// Needed for thymeleaf HTML5LEGACY mode
compile "net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:$nekoHtmlVersion"
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator") { exclude module: 'hsqldb' }
// Bean Validation
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidatorVersion"
// Jetty Server
compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:$jettyVersion"
if (!buildWar)
{
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:$jettyVersion"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:$jettyVersion"
    // Servlet API
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletApiVersion"
}
// JAX-RS REST
compile "org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:$springHk2BridgeVersion"
compile "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:$jerseyVersion"
compile "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:$jerseyVersion"
compile "org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:$jerseyVersion"
// Apache HTTP Client
compile ("org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:$jerseyVersion")
        {
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        }
// Jackson JSON
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:$jacksonVersion"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonVersion"
// Swagger Docs
compile("com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:$swaggerVersion") {
    exclude module: 'jsr311-api'
    exclude module: 'scala-compiler'
}
// JS, HTML, CSS minimizer
compile "ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-core:$wroVersion"
compile("ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-extensions:$wroVersion") {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
// Mapper
compile("net.sf.dozer:dozer:$dozerVersion") {
    exclude module: 'jcl-over-slf4j'
    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
}
// Database
compile "com.h2database:h2:$h2Version"
// Coda Hale Metrics
compile "com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:$metricsVersion"

// Utilities
// =========
compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
compile "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"

// Testing
// ========
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
}
// Mockito
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion"
// Used for asserts in verification
testCompile "org.easytesting:fest-assert:$festAssertVersion"
}
```

Console output at server startup

```
:37:38,267 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
:37:38,268 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
:37:38,268 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/Clowio/apt-crm/src/main/resources/logback.xml]
:37:38,525 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/Clowio/apt-crm/src/main/resources/logback.xml]] every 60 seconds. 
:37:38,525 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
:37:38,536 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction - begin
:37:38,620 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@71d44a3 - Adding [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml] to configuration watch list.
:37:38,620 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7b98f307 - URL [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml] is not of type file
:37:38,624 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@71d44a3 - Adding [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml] to configuration watch list.
:37:38,624 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7b98f307 - URL [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml] is not of type file
:37:38,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ConversionRuleAction - registering conversion word clr with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter]
:37:38,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ConversionRuleAction - registering conversion word wex with class [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter]
:37:38,634 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LevelRemappingAppender]
:37:38,637 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER]
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory] to ERROR
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase] to ERROR
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.coyote.http    .Http    NioProtocol] to WARN
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils] to WARN
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool] to WARN
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.crsh.plugin] to WARN
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.crsh.ssh] to WARN
:37:38,667 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle] to ERROR
:37:38,668 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] to WARN
:37:38,668 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration] to WARN
:37:38,668 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx] to false
:37:38,668 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER] to Logger[org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx]
:37:38,669 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.thymeleaf] to false
:37:38,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DEBUG_LEVEL_REMAPPER] to Logger[org.thymeleaf]
:37:38,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@71d44a3 - Adding [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml] to configuration watch list.
:37:38,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7b98f307 - URL [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml] is not of type file
:37:38,673 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
:37:38,678 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
:37:38,694 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
:37:38,769 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@71d44a3 - Adding [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml] to configuration watch list.
:37:38,769 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@7b98f307 - URL [jar:file:/Users/lalala/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml] is not of type file
:37:38,773 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
:37:38,778 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
:37:38,789 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
:37:38,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@2177849e - No compression will be used
:37:38,821 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: /var/folders/j4/ntrxjqzx5kq19hbxfwc10czc0000gn/T//spring.log
:37:38,822 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [/var/folders/j4/ntrxjqzx5kq19hbxfwc10czc0000gn/T//spring.log]
:37:38,823 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
:37:38,823 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
:37:38,823 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apt.crm] to DEBUG
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to ERROR
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to ERROR
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.orm.jpa] to ERROR
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.transaction] to DEBUG
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
:37:38,824 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
:37:38,826 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
:37:38,826 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
:37:38,826 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
:37:38,826 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@10959ece - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Comment: Few questions - Does this happen for all types of exceptions or specifically for only one or few of them like NullPointerException? Try doing a test to understand this. Also do you see the exception type in the logs without the stacktrace or just no information about the exception from the logs? Lastly is this just about exception stacktraces or about messages logged under ERROR log level?

Comment: Stack trace isn't shown for any kind of exceptions. There is no trace of any kind of exception or error in the code, just code 500 is returned at WS. Logs with DEBUG or ERROR are shown normally. I'll try to create my own exception handling, maybe Jetty eats them up :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is in this question:

[Global Exception Handling in Jersey & Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850486/global-exception-handling-in-jersey-spring)

After creating ExceptionMapper everything works fine.